# WSL2 - Podman Desktop - Access to internal services (VPN) from containers triggered in Windows are failing (running container in WSL works)

Tags: containers, windows-subsystem-for-linux, vpn, wsl-2, podman

Access to internal services via curl is failing when using podman under Windows:

```
PS C:\Users\<USER>> podman run docker.io/nicolaka/netshoot curl https://<INTERNAL_IP_OR_HOST>:6443/version --insecure
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (35) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

When triggering the same internal curl request directly in the podmans WSL distribution everything works out as well:

```
PS C:\Users\<USER>> wsl -d podman-machine-default

You will be automatically entered into a nested process namespace where
systemd is running. If you need to access the parent namespace, hit ctrl-d
or type exit. This also means to log out you need to exit twice.

[<USER>@<HOSTNAME> ~]$ podman run docker.io/nicolaka/netshoot curl https://<INTERNAL_IP_OR_HOST>:6443/version --insecure
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {},
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "Unauthorized",
  "reason": "Unauthorized",
  "code": 401
100   157  100   157    0     0   2474      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  2492
```

A ping directly from the container running under Windows is working fine (curl fails):

```
PS C:\Users\<USER>> podman run docker.io/nicolaka/netshoot ping <INTERNAL_IP_OR_HOSTNAME>
PING <INTERNAL_IP_OR_HOSTNAME> (<INTERNAL_IP_OR_HOSTNAME>) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from <INTERNAL_IP_OR_HOSTNAME>: icmp_seq=1 ttl=60 time=12.2 ms
```

Access to other external services from Windows via podman are working fine:

```
PS C:\Users\<USER>> podman run docker.io/nicolaka/netshoot curl https://google.com
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>301 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>301 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="https://www.google.com/">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
100   220  100   220    0     0   1524      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  1527
```

Has anyone seen a similar behaviour?

**Environment**

- Podman: 4.6.1
- Podman Desktop: 1.2.1
- Node OS: Windows 10
- WSL version: 2
- WSL Distribution: Default Podman Desktop distro (podman-machine-default) with enabled root privileges

**Adaptions**

Added DNS server of my internal domain to enable resolving of internal hostnames

- /etc/wsl.conf > generateResolvConf=false
- /etc/resolv.conf > contains internal DNS servers

Therefore internal hostnames can be resolved from both the Windows machine, as well as inside WSL. This is not a DNS resolution problem!

Once VPN is disconnected and I can directly reach the internal services everything is OK.

**UPDATE**

The difference between starting the container in Windows compared to WSL seems to be that the packets are fragmented. Need to investigate further in this direction. Here a Wireshark Trace:

[Wireshark Trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5cRo.png)

Answer (score 1):

**FINAL SOLUTION**

The problem was as indicated in the EDIT section the mtu size. Podman network supports the configuration of MTU sizes:

- Create new podman network with adapted MTU size:

```
podman network create podman-lower-mtu --disable-dns --opt mtu=1300
```

- Set default_network to podman-lower-mtu in wsl under path /usr/share/containers/containers.conf
- Restart WSL

Answer (score 0):

It ist Not nessesary to workarround If you Set Up Default Maschine by using Usermode Networking: true